# Upgrading standalone to replica set: Can I copy the data at the start

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

If I have a standalone Mongo 6 now (deployed using the docker image + mounted volume for data) and I want to upgrade it to a replica set. Isit ok to also copy the data dir, for the replica sets? The goal is to hopefully not require a very long sync at the start

Comment: Should be no problem, have a look at [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/). In [Add Members to a Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/#data-files) it explains how to use a copy. Note, you should take the copy of `dbPath` when the MongoDB is not running or at least after running `db.fsyncLock()` (don't forget to `db.fsyncUnlock()` afterwards)